# DirectX pEnum->Next(1,&pPin,NULL) returns S_FALSE

Tags: c++, winapi, video, directshow, video-capture

I have built filters for USB TV TUNER in graph edit and its working fine in graphedit.

When I converted it to C++ code it seems ok for TV tuner Filter as I get pins connected by calling  **`pEnum->Next(1,&pPin,NULL)`** but for USB TV Audio interface i am unable to find pins as i always get `S_FALSE` for call to `pEnum->Next(1,&pPin,NULL)` .

I have seen posts in different web sites telling that one needs to use enumerations but no example is given.
Also it is not understandable to me why tuners filter pins are accessible on same device and other's not.
Here is my code. please tell me how to change it for enumeration.

```
  HRESULT hr=S_OK;
    CComPtr<ICaptureGraphBuilder2> pBuilder;
    hr=pBuilder.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2);
    hr=pBuilder->SetFiltergraph(pGraph);

    //now add tuner
    CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pGadmeiAnalogTvTuner0001;
    hr=pGadmeiAnalogTvTuner0001.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_GadmeiAnalogTvTuner0001);
    if(hr<0) 
        return -1;
    hr=pGraph->AddFilter(pGadmeiAnalogTvTuner0001,L"Gadmei Analog TvTuner 0001");
    if(hr!=S_OK)
        return -1;
    printf("added tuner to graph \n");

    //now add tv audio
    CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pGadmeiAnalogTvAudiof;
    hr=pGadmeiAnalogTvAudiof.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_GadmeiAnalogTvAudio);
    if(hr<0) 
        return -1;
    hr=pGraph->AddFilter(pGadmeiAnalogTvAudiof,L"GadmeiAnalogTvAudio");
    if(hr!=S_OK)
        return -1;

    printf("added Tv Audio to graph \n");
    //connect tv tuner and audio
    hr=pGraph->ConnectDirect(GetPin(pGadmeiAnalogTvTuner0001,L"Analog Audio"), GetPin(pGadmeiAnalogTvAudiof,L"TVAudio In"),NULL);

    if(hr!=S_OK)
        printf("Can't Connect \n");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pins avaiable in graphstudio not there in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506451/pins-avaiable-in-graphstudio-not-there-in-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture filters are created through enumerator, where they are instantiated in proper context. `CoCreateInstance` through `CLSID` gives you a wrapper object without binding it to the hardware of interest, then you you have the typical symptom of valid inteface pointer, with however no pins available.

Comment: Please explain with code example how to use enumeration and then how should i changee addfilter code. i am not getting it right now

Comment: I linked another answer which answers the same question, with the same symptom and [links to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377566) explaining the details and providing code snippets.

Comment: I ran the code as mentioned in the link provided (MSDN) and it gives me in output my USB TV Stick information as "USB TV Device", whereas  grapghedit exposes me following filters (1)Gadmei ANALOG TV TUNER (2)Gadmei TV AUDIO (3) Gadmei ANALOG CROSSBAR (4) USB TV DEVICE (I got it when i ran MSDN example, in grapghedit its in orange color). Now why only "USB TV" is exposed only from running code and where are the filters which i see and run in grapghedit. How can i get in my program.

Comment: With a tv tuner source you nearly always need the crossbar-filter. And this filter needs to be configured correctly.

Comment: but in graphedit before crossbar there are "TV Tuner" and "Tv Audio" filters to make path for signal to "CrossBar" filter. Can any one explain with source code how to find those filters first.

Comment: GraphEdit never does `CoCreateInstance`, your code is still showing you are using it for instantiation. You are not going move on before you fix this part (filter enumerators and eventually `BindToObject` etc).